# how to resolve innodb cluster conflict

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-innodb-cluster

I am currently maintaining an innodb cluster with three nodes. It runs well but sometimes one node will be `MISSING` then I have to bring it up online again.

The problem is I inserted a table without primary key. Then a node failed.
When I want to rejoin the failure node to cluster it says it can not join because there is a table without a primary key. I altered the table in cluster to give it primary key and the failure node still complains the same. So I deleted the table in failure node and expected it will rebuild the table.

Now it says

```
ERROR: Group Replication join failed.
ERROR: Error joining instance to cluster: '192.168.123.45@3306' - Query failed. 3092 (HY000): The server is not configured properly to be an active member of the group. Please see more details on error log.. Query: START group_replication (RuntimeError)
```

after I run cluster.checkInstanceState('root@192.168.123.45:3306');

```
The instance '192.168.123.45:3306' is invalid for the cluster.
The instance contains additional transactions in relation to the cluster.

{
    "reason": "diverged", 
    "state": "error"
}
```

I know it is because the inconsistent state in different db. But I searched the internet but there's no documentation about how to resolve conflict in innodb cluster.
Any advice would be helpful!

Comment: Lots of bad things can happen without an explicit `PRIMARY KEY`.  Suggest you focus on making such for that table.

Comment: @RickJames yeah I've already add primary key into it. Thx for suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

I have fixed this issue recently, steps below:

I tried to **rejoin the instance** to cluster as follows:

```
cluster.rejoinInstance(instance);
```

Now the `cluster.status()` function reports, **member status** as **"RECOVERING"**, but after few minutes, again it reports as **"MISSING"**.

I have logged into the missing instance and verified the processlist `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` but I could not see any active traffic and I verified the data inconsistency by querying few user tables.

Also, checked the cluster status with `cluster.status({extended:true, queryMembers:true});` function and observed, `lastApplied` block and `startTimestamp` was showing the older date, this confirm that, recent transactions are not applied on this instance.

Then, I did the below steps to remove the instance from cluster:

```
cluster.removeInstance(instance);
```

And added back to the instance as below:

```
cluster.removeInstance(instance);
```

This produced the error: `The instance is already part of the another Group Replication;`

So, I queried the below table on missing instance, and figured it out the instance status again:

```
select * from performance_schema.replication_group_members;
```

To add the back to the cluster, the I have below 2 options now:

- Rebuild the instance with fresh backup and restore from primary
- Remove cluster metadata from the instance and join back to cluster.

1st option is my last choice always. So I tried the below steps:

- Step 1: `var cluster = dba.getCluster();`
- Step 2: `cluster.rescan();`
- Step 3: Press `'Y'` to remove the missing node on the interactive **MySQL
  Shell** window.
- Step 4: Login to Missing node and set the `super_read_only = OFF;`
- Step 5: Stop the group replication: `STOP GROUP_REPLICATION;`
- Step 5: Reset the slave: `RESET SLAVE ALL;`
- Step 6: Drop the cluster metadata database:

  **DROP DATABASE mysql_innodb_cluster_metadata;**
- Step 7: Go to shell and add the node back to cluster:`cluster.addInstance(instance);`
- Step 8: On interactive window: Select the recovery method as `"Clone"`
  (**MySQL 8.0.16 and above**).

I did not try `Incremental Recovery` in this case, but, in an another instance, it worked.

If you are unable to use **Clone** or **Incremental Recovery** options for any reason, use method 1 to rebuild the instance.

I hope it helps!

Comment: I also got 'addinstance already part of another InnoDB cluster' message, and these steps worked like a charm .. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Well... So I ended up partially wipe the database and resync it again by `reset master` and `drop database mysql_innodb_cluster_metadata`. Now It works fine.

Still wondering if there's anyway to rewind gtid instead of full reset...